# При открытии приложения автоматически открывается клавиатура

Tags: android, клавиатура

При открытии приложения, автоматически открывается клавиатура (только на планшетах).
Как это убрать?
В программе уже используется:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Вот тут посмотри https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
    ...
    >
```

Comment: спасибо, все работает)))